# R shiny : Read excel as dataframe

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a Shiny App where the user uploads an excel file.

This file should be saved as *data frame in Global Environment*, which I will use process later.

ui.r

```
({fileInput("Fail_i",label = "Upload Failure data in Excel",multiple = TRUE)}))
```

server.r

```
output$Fail_o = renderTable({faildata_1 = read.csv(input$Fail_i$datapath)})
```

Comment: Do you want to save it such that it is shared between different users or do you want it to be available to a particular user? Consider using [reactiveValues](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.11/reactiveValues.html)?

Comment: I want to save it as df so that I can process the data. Ex : If input has column with 1 , 1.5 , 3 , 1.8 : I want to process column 2 as log of column 1, in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you pretty close to where you want to be.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                         ".csv")),

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

      # Input: Select separator ----
      radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                   choices = c(Comma = ",",
                               Semicolon = ";",
                               Tab = "\t"),
                   selected = ","),

      # Input: Select quotes ----
      radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
                   choices = c(None = "",
                               "Double Quote" = '"',
                               "Single Quote" = "'"),
                   selected = '"'),

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
      radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                   choices = c(Head = "head",
                               All = "all"),
                   selected = "head")

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Data file ----
      tableOutput("contents")

    )

  )
)

# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$contents <- renderTable({

    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.

    req(input$file1)

    df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
             header = input$header,
             sep = input$sep,
             quote = input$quote)

    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(df))
    }
    else {
      return(df)
    }

  })

}
# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```